# Symlinking /mnt in a VM to compile file directly to VM folder

Tags: osx, virtual-machine, symlink, vmware

What I'm trying to do is symlinking a shared folder between my Mac and my Ubuntu VM.

The shared folders on the VM are going in `/mnt/hgfs/`.

On my Mac I symlink the directory (let's say `macdirectory`) to the shared folder `sharedfolder` so when I compile and put a file there, it follows to the VM directory where the application is running.

What I'm trying to do in my VM is this:

`sudo ln -s ~/linuxdirectory /mnt/hgfs/sharedfolder`

but then I get this error message:

`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/mnt/hgfs/sharedfolder/linuxdirectory'`

With my many attempts to make this symlink, I may have done bad links. This is the result of `ls -la /mnt/hgfs/sharedfolder/`

```
drwxr-xr-x 1  502 dialout  102 Jun 30 22:30 .
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root    4192 Jun 30 23:01 ..
-????????? ? ?    ?          ?            ? linuxdirectory
```

Can't I use `/mnt/` as a link?

Comment: Did you consider `mount` with `--bind` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HGFS won't allow this. No matter what you do, symlinks are only allowed from the share to other places in the share. Other links will be like that broken file you made. Normally, the guest can create symlinks, but then it cannot follow them. If you add the line

```
sharedFolder<n>.followSymlinks = "TRUE"
```

then the guest will be allowed to follow symlinks already made, but then it loses the ability to create new ones.

[Reference](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/335998)

Comment: Your first part is OK but your explanations on the VM manager make no sense as it is simply a symlink.

Comment: A symlink is not a normal file, and its semantics are nonobvious in a shared VM dir. What would happen if the guest was Windows and the Mac host created a symlink in that directory? Windows has no clue how a *nix symlink works. Secondly, which side does the symlink point to? Does it point to the guest's internal VFS when seen on that side but the host's on that side? Does it point to the guest's or the host's always? You have a security hole every way. On further thought, it's probably less "VMM doesn't know" and more "VMM disallows."

Comment: It's neither.  In the current case, you simply end up with a symlink `/mnt/hgfs/sharedfolder/linuxdirectory` that points to the non-existing `~/linuxdirectory`.  This is obviously not what OP wanted as you mentioned in the first part of your answer, but it has no relevance to the VM.  The closest I can see is that placing a symlink inside the VM's mount will not allow the VM to internally access the target, but that doesn't fit what you're saying either.

Comment: The `ln` failed. Normally, if you attempt to make broken symlink, `ln` *does not* fail. The failure of `ln` points to something more fundamental than just an accidental argument flip. This more fundamental thing is the fact that the symlink is being made in a dir shared between a VM and its host, which would be horribly insecure if it were allowed. Additionally, the statement "you simply end up with a symlink `/mnt/hgfs/sharedfolder/linuxdirectory` that points to the non-existing `~/linuxdirectory` " is false: the `ls` shows a broken file that cannot be `stat`ed properly. That's not a symlink.

Comment: I'd bet that the filesystem simply doesn't allow symlinks.  That still doesn't match your description.

Comment: On the host, the chance of the FS not supporting symlinks is tiny, because symlinks are a part of every mainstream FS (because it's a core part of \*nix). On the guest, the point is moot, because if the "FS" on the mountpoint doesn't support it, well, that "FS" is part of the VMM. Also, how does creating a symlink in a shared mount resulting in a failed syscall and a broken, un`stat`able file (as seen from the VM) not match what I said? What *did* happen, then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61408/discussion-between-htnw-and-julie-pelletier).

Comment: I don't think I flipped the `ln` args. I want to make a link from `/mnt/hgfs/linuxdirectory` to `~/linuxdirectory`. For example, when I compile, a file will go to `/mnt/hgfs/linuxdirectory` and with the symlink I want it to go to `~/linuxdirectory`. 

The broken link as dissapeared but when I try to flip the args, the link is not good (`ls -la ~/linuxdirectory` points to `/mnt/hgfs/linuxdirectory` which is not what I want)

Comment: Just saw your edit. This is unfortunate. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using Oracle VMBox and I had to allow the VM to make symlinks. Using `VBoxManage` in Windows, use this command:

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/SHARED_FOLDER 1
```

where *VM_NAME* is the name of your virtual machine, and the name of the *SHARED_FOLDER* (without path, I believe).
If the command is successful, it doesn't return anything. If not, it returns an error.